# Terraform Plan unable to finish

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a terraform code, and i'm trying to run terraform plan locally on rds module. This module was working before, I'm not sure what i messed up in my system.

```
Error: dial tcp: lookup xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com on 192.168.1.1:53: no such host

Error: could not start transaction: dial tcp: lookup xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com on 192.168.1.1:53: no such host
```

Can someone pls point me how to fix this error.

Comment: Can you show a TF code that produced the error and how to reproduce it, if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your DNS is messed up. Based on your platform, try configuring the DNS nameserver.

For example, on Linux, edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and add:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```